# Send or receive email if server get downtime

Tags: email, server, web-hosting, vps

I need some help as I have got a problem with sending and receiving my emails on my own server. I'm renting a virtual private server to allow me to host my own server and I can be able to send and receive the emails with no problem. But I have got a small problem because when someone try to send me an email and I try to send them an email, I would not be able to send or receive the email if the server get downtime.

I want to know how I can be able to send or receive the email if my server get downtime?

Do I need to buy additional IP Address or get another server to back up that if my server get downtime or what?

Or do I need to find a web host to allow me to host my domain and create email account so I could be able to send and receive the emails without I don't have to worry about anything if my server get downtime?

I don't want to get another server as it have cost me $20 per month and I don't want to get another web host to rent just for email. I want to use one server as it's cheaper for me. If you know how I can be able send or receive the emails if my server get downtime, I would appreciate for the useful information.

I am using gmail to send or receive my own domain email for free.

Any advice would be much appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are hosting your own e-mail server, use a local e-mail client and POP3/IMAP with your server. If a message is unable to be sent due to your server being down, it will be held in the program's outbox until the server is back up and running. Unfortunately this is the downside of hosting your own e-mail. There is no way of sending/receiving e-mail without a working server, just as it is impossible to send/receive phone calls if your phone line was cut.

Comment: I am using POP3 and SMTP on my server, so can I be able to send or receive the emails after when my server get back up running?  Do you think it is a good idea if I should get another server to back up or should I get a web host to allow me to send or receive my emails?

Comment: I want to use my own server because they are allowed me to send the emails up to 10k in per day.

Comment: If you're just looking for an e-mail associated with your domain, try a hosted provider so that you don't have to worry about server downtime. For example, try G Suite from Google: https://gsuite.google.com/

Comment: Yes of course I do. I have been thinking about getting G Suite, but my problem is they would not allow me to send more than 2k in per day. Do you know what is the sending limit for G Suite?

Comment: For large volume e-mail, try SendGrid: https://sendgrid.com/ . They offer e-mail hosting and an easy API for mass mailing. They also have easy to interpret statistics for your campaigns.

Comment: Thank you, if I get SendGrid to add the pop3 and smtp on my gmail, can I send more than 2k in per day or it is against gmail TOS?

Comment: SendGrid will send e-mail independently, as you will add their own servers to your domain's e-mail whitelist. You choose the e-mail address that appears to your recipients, so your GMail would receive any replies but they do not process the sent e-mails from SendGrid.

Comment: @Robert sparkpost.com are very expensive, I'd find sendgrid are much cheaper than sparkpost.com but I prefer G Suite as they are much cheaper  and offering 2k sending limit with my own domain just for $5 per month.

Comment: @RobertJones AFAIK Sparkpost free developer accounts for 15k per month.

Answer (score 0):

Emails can be sent only if your server is up and running. The sender or the receiver gets notified when the email gets bounced back. The only thing you can do is just wait for the server to run normally.